# How to MiTM insert an iframe using burp or another tool?

Tags: tls, penetration-test, cookies, man-in-the-middle, burp-suite

So, I am trying to obtain a cookie without the secure flag enabled over HTTPS.
After reading about it, I came across an answer:

1. You visit `https://secure.example.com/` which drops a cookie on
   your browser.
2. You then visit `http://www.msn.com/` however a MITM inserts:

   ```
   <div style='visibility:hidden'>
      <iframe src='http://secure.example.com/'></iframe>
   <div>
   ```
3. MiTM sniffs your cookie from the request on the iframe

I am currently trying to duplicate the above steps.

Using a proxy tool like [Burp](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html), I am able to obtain the cookies and all header information.
I am wondering, how do I insert an `iframe` with a HTTP website as a request?

Am I using the wrong tool?

Comment: AFAIK, Burp Suite already has an HTTP editor which allows you to do that, or you can [use Fiddler to modify and inject HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1933934/injecting-javascript-to-website-using-fiddler).

Comment: This tool might be more useful for you https://github.com/cortesi/mitmproxy

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using the Proxy tool (tab) of Burp. Just be sure that you added the host (msn.com in this case) to the Scope and check the "Intercept server responses..." check box on the Options tab (under Proxy).

This way all the server responses will be displayed on the Intercept tab where you can place arbitrary content in them.

You can also use the automatic Match and Replace feature under Proxy/Options.

http://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy.html